# Gradle - common part of DSL in separate (in other) git repository

Tags: gradle

We use our cusrom plugin and define the script in this way (This is an approximate pseudocode):

```
//It is common part for every script (1)
environments {
  "env1" {
    server mySettings("host1", "port1", "etc")
  }
  "env2" {
   server mySettings("host2", "port2", "etc")
  }
  ... //another common scopes
 }
```

and

```
def defaultSettings(def envHost,    def envPort = "15555"  ...) {
  return {
  // Specific settings for the current script (package names, versions etc)
  }
}
```

So in all my scripts (which are separate projects and are in separate git repositories) the common part (1) is repeated.

Is there any correct way to define the common part as a specific project (this can not be part of the plugin - the common part also changes periodically)?

I want to refer to this part when creating a new project and describe only the project-specific settings.

It looks like gradle multi-project builds, but common part should be in other git repository/Nexus.

Important clarification - the common part can also be in the Nexus, have a version ( to have POM descriptor).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common to have an "opinionated" plugin and a "base" plugin. Gradle uses this concept quite often.

One example is the `java` plugin automatically applies the `java-base` plugin. So the `java-base` plugin contains all of the tasks (logic) but doesn't actually do anything. The `java` plugin adds the tasks and configures them (eg it adds the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` conventions). So the `java-base` plugin is not opinionated, the `java` plugin is opinionated.

So, you could do the same, have a `base` plugin and a `opinionated` plugin which

1. Applies the `base` plugin
2. Configures the environments specific for your use case

Note also that you can move logic from `build.gradle` to a plugin if you put the logic within a `project.with { ... }` closure. Eg:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            subprojects { ... }
            configurations { ... }
            dependencies { ... }
            task foo(type: Bar) { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But maybe I have a slightly different problem - the basic common functionality is a script that also changes (and can quite often). I would like to apply all these changes to all my scripts. For example,  as a JAR dependency in java projects.

Comment: So pack the script inside the plugin jar and have the plugin extract the script before executing it (via `apply from:`). You could use a dynamic version (or `-SNAPSHOT` version) so that updates to the plugin will automatically flow through to the projects

Comment: Tnanks, I understood what you said, I will try this solution during couple days

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution to your problem. The approach may be less clean than using an opinionated plugin, but it allows you to manage simple Gradle scripts independently from your projects:

The `apply from:` term to include Gradle scripts is not limited to file paths, but can also handle URLs. This way, you can simply manage your scripts in a standalone repository and provide the newest version via a web server.

To test this way of script distribution and access, you can even use the raw file view feature provided by various repository platforms like GitHub or Bitbucket:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/<branch>/<file>'
```

The biggest disadvantage of this approach is the fact, that you need to have access to the local or even global web server for each build, if you need to ensure company-external or offline builds, you should stick to @LanceJavas solution and use a custom plugin.